# Outlook 2010 mail merge group

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, mail-merge

I'm trying to send a personalized email message to a contact group, but I get this error message:

> "contact groups cannot be selected.
>   you must select a contact group."

If I select individual contacts instead of contact groups, it works fine. Anyone can help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A screen shot or two of what you are trying would really help.

Comment: I agree i have never heard of an error like that, and i have Outlook 2010, a screenshot would be great